# How to take subset of csv input file for execution

Tags: csv, jmeter

I am using jmeter to test our system using the 'HTTP Request' sampler.
Some of the values in the request are parameterized using a csv file
using 'CSV Data Set Config'.

There are 600 rows in the csv file with one row used for one http request so I have Loop Count set to 600. Each row is in effect one test case. 
I only need one thread. So in my result tree I see 600 result entries when run - this is all working fine.

I am now trying to say just execute rows 10 to 15 only in the csv i.e. test cases 10 to 15 instead of all 600. I have tried to get something like this working mostly through the use of Controllers but I am missing something.

Could anybody point me in the right direction on this please ?
Thanks in advance - Ian.

Answer (score 0):

Add a [counter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Counter) before your request with the below configurations:

- **Start:** 1
- **Increment:** 1
- **Reference Name:** Counter

Then put your request inside an [If controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller) with this condition `${__javaScript("${Counter}" > 9 && "${Counter}" < 16)}`

This will make your script execute only rows from 10 to 15.

Answer (score -1):

I believe the fastest and the easiest solution would be generating a brand new CSV file containing only necessary rows **before** your test like:

1. Add [setUp Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#setUp_Thread_Group) to your Test Plan
2. Add [Test Action](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Action) Sampler to the setUp Thread Group (you don't need an extra result, don't you?)
3. Add [JSR223 PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) as a child of the Test Action Sampler
4. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   new File('/path/to/original.csv').readLines()[9..14].each {line ->
       new File('/path/to/new.csv') << line << System.getProperty('line.separator')
   }
   ```
5. Amend your test to use `new.csv` instead of the `original.csv`

Of course change `/path/to/original.csv` to real path of the "source" CSV file with 600 entries, the same for the `new.csv`. The paths can be either absolute or relative.

See [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article for more information on Groovy scripting in JMeter tests.